# Error on updating a specific table row : jquery.dataTables.js:8149 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'aoData' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I am trying to update a DataTable row but its throwing an error:

> jquery.dataTables.js:8149 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'aoData' of undefined

This is the code that I am using to update the row with index 0:

```
var rowindex = 0;
var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();
table.row(rowindex).data(['1', '2', '3']).draw();
```

According to the [official documentation of DataTable](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().data()) this is how we are suppose to update a single row with new data.

**EDIT. Datatable:**

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<table id="myTable" class="display compact" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Reg</th>  
            <th>Edit</th>                   
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach (get_all_customers_list() as $user) { ?>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b> <?php echo $user["recipient_name"]; ?></b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo $user["registration_date"]; ?>
                    </td>                       
                    <td>
                        <button type="button" id="button_edit" onclick='edit_customer_request(<?php echo json_encode($user); ?>)' value="<?php echo $user; ?>" name="edit_customer">Edit</button>                             
                    </td>
                </tr>
        <?php }?>
    </tbody>
```

Comment: I am not able to recreate your issue. Using your code I can update a table row. Can you edit your question to show more details, including the jQuery and DataTables scripts you are using, the HTML table, and some initial sample data?

Comment: @andrewjames sure. I just updated my question with the table.

Comment: @andrewjames and?

Comment: Thank you for providing the extra info. Can you provide the other items I mentioned, also?

Comment: @andrewjames I just did. Please take a look!

Comment: I am still unable to recreate your error. The row update works fine. My simplified test version of your code removes the PHP directives, and uses hard-coded table data. Apart from that, it is a copy of your code.